# Would using a higher voltage solar panel improve my project?

Tags: solar-cell

For fun, I removed the batteries from a small radio and replaced it with a 1 watt, 3 volt solar panel directly. In full sun, it works just fine (listenable volume, good reception), but as soon as a cloud comes by, or a shadow passes over, the radio cuts out. This is a pain because once this happens, and the sun comes back out, the radio doesn't turn back on. I have to switch it off and back on again.

Would getting a higher voltage panel and a buck converter help? Maybe just another 3 volt panel with a higher wattage? I even played with the idea of using a supercapacitor to fill in the gaps, but that seems like an expensive way to go, seeing as they cost almost twice as much as the radio does.

I'm a new hobbyist and would love to get some opinions and maybe even be pointed in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: `would love to get some opinions` ..  questions asking for opinions are off topic here

Comment: The sun's intensity is roughly 1/10 on a cloudy day. So, you need a solar array about 10 times as large. Or, parallel 10 of the same as what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know enough about buck converters to directly answer your question, but here's an alternative idea:

**Your problem**

A photovoltaic module (solar panel) is a voltage-limited, light dependent *current source.* 3V is the limiting voltage of your module, but when that cloud covered up the sun, the voltage dropped because your module no longer could supply as much current as the radio wanted.

**My proposal**

Since the problem is the current limit, you could address that by putting several 3V modules in parallel with each other. The parallel array would be able to supply enough current at 3V to run your radio with less illumination than a single module would need.

**The alternative**

I'll say again, I don't know much about buck converters. I can't say whether
the total number of modules you'd need to run your radio on a cloudy day would be less if you put them in parallel, or less if you put them in series and *efficiently* regulated the voltage down to 3V.

One thing to note about putting modules in series though: The current of any single module is limited by the illumination. So, shading even a single module will limit the current of the entire series string of which it is a member.*

---

* But, google for "PV module" and "bypass diode" to learn a work-around for that.

P.S., [Here's a page that explains PV modules in more detail](https://pvpmc.sandia.gov/modeling-steps/2-dc-module-iv/diode-equivalent-circuit-models/). When you read it, note that, \$I_L\$
is determined entirely by the intensity of illumination.